# Send an email where sender address is pulled from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I am working on a simple application where a user will authenticate and after authentication, the page will display current course information for that user.  They use a form to send selected information in an email.  What I am attempting to do is have the mail.From pull the email address from a database.  I have looked in forums and tried a few things out.  I am stuck.  What I have tried is below.

```
[CAS.CasAuth]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly PeopleEntities _db = new PeopleEntities();

    [Authentication.Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var currentUser = Authentication.CurrentUser.user;
        var classes = _db.vw_People.ToList();

        return View(classes.Where(x => x.user == currentUser));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string[] courseid)
    {
        SendEmail(null, null, null, null, null, null);

        return View();
    }

    private bool SendEmail(string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("test@test.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_db.vw_People.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Email_Addr.ToString()));
        mail.Subject = "Test Test test";
        mail.Body = "Test";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp-settings", 25);
        // smtp.Host = "smtp-settings";
        //smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test", "password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
     var sender = _db.vw_People.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Email_Addr);
     mail.From = new MailAddress(sender);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the error is or why your approach is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that with this line, in fact, I'm not sure how this line is even compiling, is `Email_Addr` a `bool`?:

```
_db.vw_People.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Email_Addr);
```

You are trying to get the first person in the database and then select their e-mail address. All you're actually doing is selecting the `People` object.

Try this instead:

```
var sender = _db.vw_People.First().Email_Addr
```

Comment: I was able to send an email and it went to the right recipient.  The email was sent from the first address listed in the database, which is correct in the code.  If the person is not first in the database, how would "var sender" be set then?  It should pull the email address of the person who is authenticated.

Comment: var sender = _db.vw_People.First(x => x.Email_Addr == from).Email_Addr

Comment: I have been trying different ways with the above code.  The closest I can get to compiling returns an error due to sender being null.

Comment: I was able to get the appropriate sender.  I needed to do this: var sender = Authentication.CurrentUser.email_addr in order to get the address of the authenticated user.  Thanks for the help jumpingcode